# c++ inplace_merge expression: sequence not ordered

Tags: c++

The following codes work for some data file, but for some other data files it didn't work, the following screen displayed:

[image]

Anyone can help to resolve this problem?

```
if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    {
        int s = parsed_contents.size();
        parsed_contents += QString(file.readAll()).split("\n").filter(datestr);
        std::inplace_merge (parsed_contents.begin(), parsed_contents.begin() + s, parsed_contents.end(), [&](const QString &a, const QString &b) -> bool
        {
           QDateTime dt_a = (dt.indexIn(a) != -1)?QDateTime().fromString(dt.cap(2) + "-" + year + " " + dt.cap(3), "MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss:zzz"):QDateTime();
           QDateTime dt_b = (dt.indexIn(b) != -1)?QDateTime().fromString(dt.cap(2) + "-" + year + " " + dt.cap(3), "MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss:zzz"):QDateTime();

           return dt_a < dt_b;
        });
        file.close();
    }
```

Comment: sequence not ordered

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, meaning that other users with the same problem are less likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the pre-requisites for [`std::inplace_merge`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/inplace_merge/) is that the data already be sequenced (in order).

> The elements in both ranges shall already be ordered according to this same criterion (operator< or comp). The resulting range is also sorted according to this.

You need to sort your lists according to the same `operator<` prior to merging.